# I am updating Image fields in my SQL table using Asp.net. It give me a multi-part Identifier bound error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am storing the users current Identity in the user name variable, and using that variable to compare inside the query!

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string constr = "Data Source=Talhamalik\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Moodee;Integrated Security=True";
        int length = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
        byte[] pic = new byte[length];
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(pic, 0, length);
        string Username = Page.User.Identity.Name.Trim(); 
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    //calling connection method
                    //inserting uploaded image query
                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Update Users Set Image=@Image, ImageName =@Name where [Email] =" + Username, con);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", pic);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
                    com.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to surround username with quotes

Try this

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Update Users Set Image=@Image, ImageName =@Name 
where [Email] ='" + Username+"'", con);
```

Comment: Thanks . That Totally worked! You are a life saviour :)

Comment: Well. Then you may need to accept it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a parameter for the username value as well, it will protect you against sql-injection,,,,,, something like....

```
 SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Update Users Set Image=@Image, ImageName =@Name where [Email] = @Username", con);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", pic);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
    com.Connection = con;
```

Comment: That Worked Too ! Thanks